# Char pointer assign

Tags: c, pointers

```
char *reverse(char *str){
    
    char *reverse,*temp;
    int size = length(str);

    temp = reverse;
    
    /*go to last adress str*/
    while(*str != '\0'){
        str++;
    }
    
    /*copy str in reverse to reverse*/
    do{
        str--;
        *reverse = *str;
        reverse++;
        size--;
    }while(size >= 0);
    
    
    return temp;
}
```

In this function, I get segmentation error when I assign reverse pointer to temp pointer. if i add `reverse = (char*)malloc(size*sizeof(char));` it works fine. but does it have to work without adding it as a result, hasn't it already received an address.Is it because the length of the next address is about integer.

Comment: Since `reverse` is uninitialized, there's no reason why it should be pointing at memory that you can modify.

Comment: Do I always need to initialize so I can trade with pointers.what is the reason of this. Doesn't it point to a random memory as much as that char size?

Comment: A pointer never ever points to anything useful unless you explicitly make it do so.

Comment: Well, is there any source that you would suggest to follow this pointer topic(website,book...)?

Comment: regarding; `int size = length(str);`  What is `length`?  You could use: `size_t size = strlen( str );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `reverse` is just a pointer and actually there is no memory allocated where it can point to.
You can use `malloc()` or you can simply pass `reverse` as an additional argument to the function. Then you just need to be sure that it is allocated by the caller and that the size fits.

If it would be possible to point to anywhere in memory and to simply write data anywhere you want to then all programs and even the whole operating system would crash or viruses can directly infect everything... ;-)